# Asignar e imprimir valores a datos iguales con python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, csv

Tengo un programa que genera un CSV con datos de una BD en Sqlite.
El programa funciona seleccionando una ***Zona*** en el combobox y con esto se imprimen los datos elegidos.

Mi problema es que quisiera seleccionar una ***Zona*** y que lo que se agregue en los ***Entry*** se aplique a todos los datos que tengan la misma zona. El primer entry llamado "Grupo perteneciente" es lo que se imprime en la columna "Grupo"

Por ejemplo: Si seleccionamos ***zona Oeste*** en el combobox y contestamos el ***primer entry*** con "2" debería de verse así el csv: donde la columna "ID_Contestado" es el Entry llenado o sea 1. y la columna "Grupo" es lo que se escribió dentro del entry que en este caso es "2". y eso mismo se aplique a todos los que compartan la misma zona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inserto aquí mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os 
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3


root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x310")
root.config(bg="dark cyan")

#####---Generador de CSV---#####
def Datos1():     
      Combo1_info = Combo1.get()
      Entry1_info = En1.get()
      Entry2_info = En2.get()
      Entry3_info = En3.get()
      
      #####---En esta consulta se muestra lo que aparecerá en el combobox--#####
      conn = sqlite3.connect('FutDB.db')
      cur = conn.cursor()
      query = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Equipos where Zona=?",(Combo1.get(),))
      data = []    
      resultado= cur.fetchall()
      
      
      ID = resultado[0][0]
      Equipo = resultado[0][1]
      Pais = resultado[0][2]
      Zona = resultado[0][3]
      Titulos_loc = resultado[0][4]
      Titulos_int = resultado[0][5]
      Nuevo_Grupo = resultado[0][6]
      cur.close()
      conn.close()
      
      data = {"ID":[ID], 
              "Equipo":[Equipo], 
              "Pais":[Pais], 
              "Zona":[Zona], 
              "Titulos_loc":[Titulos_loc], 
              "Titulos_int":[Titulos_int],
              "Grupo":[Entry1_info],# <--- No se que poner aquí
              "ID_Contestado":[]} # <--- Ni aquí
      
      archivo = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient ='index')
      archivo = archivo.transpose()
      archivo.to_csv("DATOS.csv", mode="a",index=None, header=not os.path.isfile("Data1.csv"))
           
#####---Diseño---#####
Frame1 = Frame(root, bd=2, padx=10, pady=3)
Label(Frame1, text="Seleccione una zona: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)

Label1 = Label(Frame1, text="Grupo perteneciente, valor=1: ")
Label2 = Label(Frame1, text="Valor del entry = 2: ")
Label3 = Label(Frame1, text="Valor del entry = 3: ")

En1 = Entry(Frame1, font=('Times', 14), width=9)
En2 = Entry(Frame1, font=('Times', 14), width=9)
En3 = Entry(Frame1, font=('Times', 14), width=9)
Combo1 = ttk.Combobox(Frame1, font=('Times', 15), width=25)

Label1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky=E)
Label2.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky=E)
Label3.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10, padx=20, sticky=E)

En1.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=30, sticky=W)
En2.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=30, sticky=W)
En3.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=30, sticky=W)

Combo1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky=W)

Boton1 = Button(Frame1, text="Generar CSV", width=10, command = Datos1).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
Frame1.place(x=20, y=40)

#####---Consulta a la DB---#####
def combo_Name():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('FutDB.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Zona FROM Equipos')
    
    data = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return data    
    
Combo1['values'] = combo_Name() 

   
root.mainloop()
```

lo unico que se logra con mi código es esto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Espero haberme explicado bien y cualquier cosa agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: ten en cuenta que si vas ha hacer la *modificación* dentro de tu función `Datos1()` los valores no se van a actualizar, sino que se insertarán nuevos datos

Comment: lo que quieres es actualizar los valores existentes (ósea agregar el `ID_contestado` y `Grupo`) ó quieres generar el csv ya con esos daos?

Comment: Más que actualizar, es agregar al CSV esas 2 columnas.  una donde se vea el "ID" de la casilla contestada y en la otra columna ver lo que se agregó

Comment: ósea tienes que volver a leer el csv y agregar esas columnas??

Comment: no no, es generar el csv de una ya con todas las columnas, pero no se como agregar el ID de la casilla

Comment: no creo que sea la mejor opción ya que tendrías que hacer la asignación al momento de generar el csv.

Comment: sería mejor si creas tu csv y luego vas *actualizando* los valores, esto facilitará muchas cosas

Comment: Crees poder darme un ejemplo? o decirme en que parte podría corregir por favor?

Comment: ok, ahora escribo una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Como dije en mi comentario, al tener tu código en la función `Datos1()` se estarán agregando más valores a tu csv ya existente y no creo que sea eso lo que quieres, por otra parte es recomendable que cada función se encargue de una cosa en especifico, esto ayuda a tener un código limpio, ordenado y escalable.

Para *actualizar* los valores tenemos 2 opciones, 1. crear las nuevas columnas y asignarle el valor ó 2. tener ya creadas las columnas y luego solo actualizar el valor. En mi opinión creo que mejor será la opción 2, así que usaré esa.

En primer lugar al generar el csv, tendremos que poner unos valores por defecto, yo usaré los ceros `0`.

```py
def Datos1():
    ...
      
    data = {"ID":[ID], 
              "Equipo":[Equipo], 
              "Pais":[Pais], 
              "Zona":[Zona], 
              "Titulos_loc":[Titulos_loc], 
              "Titulos_int":[Titulos_int],
              "Grupo":[0], #valor por defecto
              "ID_Contestado":[0]} #valor por defecto
```

Luego para actualizar los datos crearemos esa función.

```py
def update_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("DATOS.csv")
    zona = Combo1.get()
    grupo = En1.get()
    contestado = En1.get()
    #reemplazamos los valores de la columna grupo y id_contestado con los del entry
    df.loc[df["Zona"]== zona,["Grupo","ID_contestado"]] = [grupo,contestado] #reemplazzamos si la zona es igual a la elegida
    df.to_csv("DATOS.csv") #guardamos
```

Comment: De la forma en que lo pones sale excelente, pero el problema es que de verdad es necesario que el programa creara el csv, también que se le agregaran esos nuevos campos de "Grupo" y "ID_Contestado" a todos los otros datos que tengan la misma zona en común

Comment: Si se agrega a todos los datos con la misma zona, pues ahí se aplica un filtro de pandas para hacer la nueva asignación

Comment: Al contrario, quiero asignar los mismos valores a los que tengan la misma zona.

Comment: Eso es lo que hace :/

Comment: no, no salen solo se le asigna a un valor de cierta zona. Esperaría que fuera a todos los de la misma zona. También lo que veo es que forzosamente el csv ya tiene que estar contestado si no tampoco :/

Comment: Se le asigna el valor a todas las zonas que coincidan con lo seleccionado en el combobox. En el csv no tiene que estar contestado  solo se le asigna un valor por defecto que podría ser vacío `""`, también se puede agregar las columnas pero es mucho más código

Comment: Ya lo comprobé y de verdad que si no tiende datos, no los actualiza. de igual forma viéndolo tampoco me da el ID que fue llenado. le he estado moviendo algunas cosas pero aun sin éxito.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127850/discussion-between-christian-and-truman9084).